# Difference between =text= and ~text~ in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, text-properties

On org-mode's website, `=text=` is called "verbatim", whereas `~text~` is called "code". However, when exporting an org document to LaTeX, both are translated to `\texttt{text}`. When exporting to HTML, both are translated to `<code>text</code>`.

Is there a difference between them? I'm particularly interested in LaTeX export. If there is no difference, what's the reason for these synonymous formatting options?

Comment: They're not identical for all export formats. For instance for texinfo export (`(require 'ox-texinfo)`, `C-c C-e i t`), they're different. Interestingly, `pandoc` seems to treat `=text=` and `~text~` as identical (using `pandoc -i foo.org -o bar.org` causes all `~text~` to be converted to `=text=`).